# c# Storyboard Begin() Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have about 50 `<Path>` elements on a canvas via a `<Viewbox>`. The `<Viewbox>`is also nested. I would like to change the opacity of the `<Path>` when their locations match sensor data location. The code works all the way up to the Begin() method. It doesn't give an error, it doesn't do anything. I also tried creating different `NameScopes` but couldn't pin point the correct namspace. Anything other than `this` does not make it to the Begin() method. If I create a new Scope inside of the if statement: "`if (wantedNode is System.Windows.Shapes.Path)`" it makes it to Begin() once, doesn't fire, and never comes back!

```
if (angle > 0)
        { 
            if (angle <= 180 && angle > 150)
            {
                if (mag <= sweetSpot)
                {
                    //posAlertTxt.Text = "On target...";
                }
                else if (mag <= step)
                {
                    selectedStep = "step0108";
                }
                else if (mag <= step * 2)
                .
                .
                .
                .
```

After all of the angles and magnitudes are covered:

```
 redBrush.Color = Colors.IndianRed;

            System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation opacityAnimation = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.DoubleAnimation();

            opacityAnimation.To = 1.0;
            opacityAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            opacityAnimation.AutoReverse = true;

            RegisterName("redBrush", redBrush);

            Storyboard sb = new System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard();

            Storyboard.SetTargetName(opacityAnimation, "redBrush");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath(SolidColorBrush.OpacityProperty));

            sb.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);

            object wantedNode = indicatorBounds.FindName(selectedStep);
            if (wantedNode is System.Windows.Shapes.Path){   
                System.Windows.Shapes.Path wantedChild = wantedNode as System.Windows.Shapes.Path;
                wantedChild.Fill = redBrush;
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(wantedChild.Opacity);          
                sb.Begin(this);
```

And finally, the XAML:

```
.
.
. 
.
<Viewbox Name="forceGradientContainer"  Width="126" Height="457"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Canvas.Left="117" Canvas.Top="17">
   <Canvas  Name="indicatorBounds" Width="126.378" Height="457.004">
        <Canvas Name="holder">
            .
            .
            .
            .
             <Path Fill="IndianRed" Opacity="0" x:Name="step0108" Data="F1 M 28.802,209.027 L     49.252,221.067 C 47.922,223.377 47.162,226.057 47.162,228.917 L 23.432,228.917 C 23.432,221.667 25.392,214.867 28.802,209.027 Z"/>`
            .
            .
            .
         </Canvas>    
     </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, redBrush);
```

instead of

```
RegisterName("redBrush", redBrush);
Storyboard.SetTargetName(opacityAnimation, "redBrush");
```

And why dont you just animate the opacity of the element itself?

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, wantedChild);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation, new PropertyPath("Opacity"));
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! It looks like the AutoReverse parameter is not working correctly. It must be because the function is called again when the sensor moves (before the previous call can fade out). Anyway to bubble this?

Comment: Try setting the AutoReverse-property at your Storyboard-instance: `sb.AutoReverse = true;`. Maybe the opacityAnimation adopts the value of AutoReverse while adding it to `sb`, which is false by default.

Comment: No go. I ended up creating another animation after the first begin that takes the opacity to 0. It is still kinda iffy but does a better job.